# Creating a CCSprite from "CCTextureCache"

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

So I am preloading most of my resources into the `CCTextureCache` and I am wondering how I go about creating sprites from the `CCTextureCache`. I know that in general I usually just do `CCSprite spriteWithFile`` But I am not sure how to go about accessing my textures once they are cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well

```
CCSprite *spr = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"theSprite.png"];
```

actually puts the texture in cache with the file name as key.

so

```
CCTexture2D * tex = [CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache:textureForKey:@"theSprite.png"];
```

will actually give you back the sprite's texture.

One last bit : before putting the texture in cache, the CCSprite constructor verifies if the cache already contains a texture with the key. If it does, it skips a whole bunch of steps and returns you the sprite constructed with the cached texture.

Comment: So does that mean for each sprite I would need to call                               `CCTexture2D * tex = [CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache:textureForKey:@"theSprite.png"];
`

Comment: no, just keep calling spriteWithFile. If a texture with this filename is already cached, it will use the cached texture.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CCTexture2D *pText = [CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache:textureForKey: @"(your picture filename)"];

CCSprite *pSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture: pText];
```

Read reference here(you can get almost everything you want from the reference):

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_sprite.html